# mysql: truncating a field and aggregating the data in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has a date in the form of date time.

```
mysql> select * from topsmsspammers_hour limit 1;
+---------------------+------+---------+-------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+----------------+
| date                | spam | suspect | clean | spammer      | spam_campaign_id                            | messageType | policy | isSenderPolicy |
+---------------------+------+---------+-------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+----------------+
| 2013-06-11 23:00:00 |    1 |       0 |     0 | +12073708065 | NotSet|Message35392HerbisReallyWorkingRealy |           4 |      1 |              1 |
+---------------------+------+---------+-------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I want to use the data in this table to populate an aggregate day date table with the exact same column names but with the date truncated (and counts changed to reflect the change)
I first identified the select query that would truncate the data i need:

```
mysql> select SUBSTRING_INDEX(date, ' ', 1) as date, sum(spam) as spam, sum(suspect) as suspect, sum(clean) as clean, spammer, spam_campaign_id, messageType, policy, isSenderPolicy from topsmsspammers_hour group by date, spammer, spam_campaign_id, messageType, policy, isSenderPolicy limit 1;
+------------+------+---------+-------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+----------------+
| date       | spam | suspect | clean | spammer      | spam_campaign_id                            | messageType | policy | isSenderPolicy |
+------------+------+---------+-------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+----------------+
| 2013-06-11 |    1 |       0 |     0 | +12073708065 | NotSet|Message35392HerbisReallyWorkingRealy |           4 |      1 |              1 |
+------------+------+---------+-------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+----------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (1.66 sec)

mysql>
```

I then tried to use that select query to populate the new table but the truncated date was not inserted. Rather the original date was inserted:

```
mysql> insert into topsmsspammers_day (date, spam, suspect, clean, spammer, spam_campaign_id, messageType, policy, isSenderPolicy) select SUBSTRING_INDEX(date, ' ', 1) as date, sum(spam) as spam, sum(suspect) as suspect, sum(clean) as clean, spammer, spam_campaign_id, messageType, policy, isSenderPolicy from topsmsspammers_hour group by date, spammer, spam_campaign_id, messageType, policy, isSenderPolicy limit 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (1.68 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> select * from topsmsspammers_day limit 1;                                                                +---------------------+------+---------+-------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+----------------+
| date                | spam | suspect | clean | spammer      | spam_campaign_id                            | messageType | policy | isSenderPolicy |
+---------------------+------+---------+-------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+----------------+
| 2013-06-11 00:00:00 |    1 |       0 |     0 | +12073708065 | NotSet|Message35392HerbisReallyWorkingRealy |           4 |      1 |              1 |
+---------------------+------+---------+-------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I tried then changing the data to have a different name for populating the new table but this still resulted in the full date getting inserted into the table:

```
mysql> insert into topsmsspammers_day (date, spam, suspect, clean, spammer, spam_campaign_id, messageType, policy, isSenderPolicy) select SUBSTRING_INDEX(date, ' ', 1) as dayDate, sum(spam) as spam, sum(suspect) as suspect, sum(clean) as clean, spammer, spam_campaign_id, messageType, policy, isSenderPolicy from topsmsspammers_hour group by dayDate, spammer, spam_campaign_id, messageType, policy, isSenderPolicy limit 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (1.75 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from topsmsspammers_day limit 1;
+---------------------+------+---------+-------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+----------------+
| date                | spam | suspect | clean | spammer      | spam_campaign_id                            | messageType | policy | isSenderPolicy |
+---------------------+------+---------+-------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+----------------+
| 2013-06-11 00:00:00 |    1 |       0 |     0 | +12073708065 | NotSet|Message35392HerbisReallyWorkingRealy |           4 |      1 |              1 |
+---------------------+------+---------+-------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I even tried changing the name in the insert but that fell over on the name not being a field in the new table:

```
mysql> insert into topsmsspammers_day (dayDate, spam, suspect, clean, spammer, spam_campaign_id, messageType, policy, isSenderPolicy) select SUBSTRING_INDEX(date, ' ', 1) as dayDate, sum(spam) as spam, sum(suspect) as suspect, sum(clean) as clean, spammer, spam_campaign_id, messageType, policy, isSenderPolicy from topsmsspammers_hour group by dayDate, spammer, spam_campaign_id, messageType, policy, isSenderPolicy limit 1;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'dayDate' in 'field list'
mysql>
```

What am I missing? How can I insert the truncated aggregated data into the new table?

A

it looks like 2013-06-11 23:00:00 was changed to 2013-06-11 00:00:00 so maybe its a problem with the dataType
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the datatype of your column, i guess you are using datetime. Change it to Date datatype